# Looking for an example for the projection's theorem on an inner product space?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, inner-products, projection

I'm looking for an example of a non-empty, non-convex and complete subset $C$ of an incomplete inner product space $E$ such that if we apply the projection's theorem on $C$ it gives several (maybe infinitely many) solutions or none.

I already have two examples in the case of Hilbert spaces with a non-empty, non-convex and closed (hence complete) subset $C$. Each case is solved depending on the compactness of $C$.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ell_0$ be the sapce of real sequences with finitely many non-zero terms with the norm induced by $\ell_2$. Let $C=\{e_1,e_2,..\}$. Then $C$ is complete and the distance from $0$ to $C$ is $1$. This distance is achieved at every pint of $C$.

Comment: Thank you ! Does $e_i$ stands for the canonical sequence with just a $1$ on the $i^{th}$ component ? If so, your $C$ is not convex because for instance $\dfrac{e_1+e_2}{2} \not \in C$ ? Why $C$ is complete with the norm induced by $\ell^2$ ? Because $C$ is a compact set ? How could we prove this ?

Comment: Yes, $(e_n)$ is the canonical sequence.  Yes, $\frac {e_1+e_2} 2 \notin C$. Since the distance between $e_n$ and $e_m$ is $\sqrt 2$ for $n \neq m$ any Cauchy sequence in $C$ is constant after some stage. So it is convergent. @Maman

Comment: Thanks for the precisions ! It seems also that your set $C$ is closed in $\ell_0$ ?

Comment: Yes it is closed.  @Maman

Comment: I guess to have the other case, we will need a subset $C$ which is not compact !?